# Sine Series using c

Tags: c, trigonometry, series

I have trying to generate terms of sine series and sum up their values. But I am facing error in it. As we have alternate + and - terms I have two for loops for it.
After accepting the values, the code stops working. The problem is with the for loops used for generating terms. As array part is working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i, number, j, x, value, value1, sign = 0;
    float sum, sub, res, term = 0;
    int fact = 1;
    printf("Enter the number of terms:\n");
    scanf("%d", & number);
    int a[(number)];
    //Storing odd numbers in array for terms//
    for (i = 0; i <= (2 * number); i++) {
        if ((i % 2) != 0) {
            a[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("Enter the value for x:");
    scanf("%d", & x);
    //Generating term//
    for (j = 0; j <= number;) {
        a[j] = value;
        value = value1;
        //Finding factorial//
        while (value > 1) {
            fact = fact * value;
            value = value - 1;
        }
        term = (pow(value1, j) / fact);
        sum = sum + term;
        j = j + 2;
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= number;) {
        a[j] = value;
        value = value1;
        //Finding factorial//

        while (value > 1) {
            fact = fact * value;
            value = value - 1;
        }

        term = (pow(value1, j) / fact);
        sub = sub - term;
        j = j + 2;
    }

    res = sum - sub;

    printf("%f", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*As array part is working fine*". Don't think that's true. `j` is uninitialised so `a[j] = i; j++;` are accessing indeterminate values. `a[j] = value;` has the same problem as `value` is also uninitalised.

Comment: Unrelated: your indentation could improve substantially. Possibly unrelated: forget `float` exists, use only `double`.

Comment: I hope the code doesn't look like that in your editor

Comment: @pmg please remember there are many CPU's architecture that like float instead of double.

Comment: @CarloBanfi That is true, but I highly doubt OP is coding for one of those

Comment: ASMITH, Do you think `int i, number, j, x, value, value1, sign = 0;` initializes all the listed variables to 0 or just `sign`?

Answer (score 1):

Variable `value1` is used without ever being initialized.  Additionally, it looks like it’s intended to be updated, but it is never assigned anywhere in the program.

Should `value = value1;` actually be `value1 = value;` in two cases?

Additionally, `value`, `sum` and `sub` are not initialized to zero before their first use.  To initialize these variables in the declaration, you should add `= 0` for each.

Comment: Same for `sum, sub, value`,

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good point.